# What is the best way to create git tags from Azure Pipelines?

Tags: powershell, automation, scripting, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I'm currently using an extension to create the git tag, my problem is that I'm using the Azure Platform to add the variables instead of the yaml file.

```
- task: GitTag@6
          displayName: 'Creating Git Tag'
          inputs:
            workingdir: '$(SYSTEM.DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)'
            git: '$(Major).$(Minor).$(Patch)'
```

The Variables are:

```
Name:
Major
Value:
1

Name:
Minor
Value:
0

Name:
Patch
Value:
$[counter(format('{0}.{1}', variables['Major'], variables['Minor']), 0)]
```

The current output is the following:

```
1.0.0
```

My question would be: How can I declare the Patch as a variable in the yaml file. I tried to add the following variables:

```
- name: Major
  value: 1
- name: Minor
  value: 0
- name: patch
  value: echo "##vso$[counter(format('{0}.{1}', variables['Major'], variables['Minor']), 0)]"
```

Now my new output is:

```
1.0.$[counter(format('{0}.{1}', variables['Major'], variables['Minor'])
```

Does anyone knows how can I add a script as a variable inside of the yaml file?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the *Run Inline Powershell* Azure Pipelines task, like so:

```yaml
- task: InlinePowershell@1
  inputs:
    Script: |
      $foo = 'bar'
      Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=foo;]$foo"
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem